# I have an usb to ethernet adapter, model no: VK-QF9700. can someone have driver for it

Tags: usb, ethernet, lan

I tried to update and install net-tools,flex,eveusb also tried build essential but its show this error "E: The package eveusb needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.".

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0fe6:9702 ICS Advent USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adaptor
```

I got this "E: The package eveusb needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it." while install some packages may be *usb-net tools*

Output of ***usb-devices | awk '/9702/' RS=***

```
T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  5 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0fe6 ProdID=9702 Rev=01.01
S:  Product=USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adaptor
C:  #Ifs= 2 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=122mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage
E:  Ad=05(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=84(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=86(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   8 Ivl=1ms
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 3 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
E:  Ad=02(O) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=81(I) Atr=02(Bulk) MxPS=  64 Ivl=0ms
E:  Ad=83(I) Atr=03(Int.) MxPS=   8 Ivl=1ms
```

In the device itself it has windows *.exe* file and mac os *.pkg* file.

I found this from internet but don't know this is correct or not *"*[https://github.com/pgquiles/qf9700*"](https://github.com/pgquiles/qf9700*%22)*

***$ inxi -nxxx***

```
Network:Device-1: Broadcom and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: wl v: kernel port: 6040 
           bus ID: 0d:00.0 chip ID: 14e4:4365 
           IF: wlp13s0 state: up mac: 44:1c:a8:f6:32:ef 
           Device-2: ICS Advent USB 2.0 10/100M Ethernet Adaptor type: USB driver: usb-storage bus ID: 2-2:7 
           chip ID: 0fe6:9702
```

If I try ***sudo make*** showing this errors

```
Building QF9700 USB2NET chip driver...
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-58-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:217: archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-58-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:10: all] Error 2
```

Comment: There is no package called `eveusb` in the Ubuntu repositories. Where did you originally get it from?

Comment: Now please add output of `usb-devices | awk '/9702/' RS=` command. Please format the output using the `{}` icon, not like you did the last time.

Comment: It looks like there is no Linux driver for this device.

Comment: it is an usb_modeswitch device: see this answer for commands https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/722131/usb-ethernet-adapter-not-working

Comment: @Rinzwind It is correct, but still there is no working driver for Linux.

Comment: I could only suggest getting another adapter.

Comment: or virus alert, if the same thing... 

https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=eveusb&ia=images
https://github.com/ausaf-a/eveusb   "Proof of concept of the BadUSB exploit using Digispark Attiny85 board. Useful for executing payloads on unlocked machines. Read the original paper here."

Comment: I tried with another adapter it's working but the speed is 10mb after changing the speed to 100mb it's turned off. and after removing and inserting again the speed is 10mb its did not changed..